# Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I worked with a Spring Boot project that reads CSV files and saves the data in the H2 database.

The CSV files are provided below-

```
authors.csv

email;firstname;lastname 
null-walter@echocat.org;Paul;Walter 
null-mueller@echocat.org;Max;Mülle
```

books.csv

```
title;isbn;bookAuthors;description 

Ich helfe dir kochen. Das erfolgreiche Universalkochbuch mit großem Backteil;5554-5545-4518;null-walter@echocat.org,boby-walter@echocat.org;Auf der Suche nach einem Basiskochbuch steht man heutzutage vor einer Fülle von Alternativen. Es fällt schwer, daraus die für sich passende Mixtur aus Grundlagenwerk und Rezeptesammlung zu finden. Man sollte sich darüber im Klaren sein, welchen Schwerpunkt man setzen möchte oder von welchen Koch- und Backkenntnissen man bereits ausgehen kann.
```

magazines.csv

```
title;isbn;bookAuthors;publishedAt 

Beautiful cooking;5454-5587-3210;null-walter@echocat.org;21.05.2011
```

I write the POJO files,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;


    // email;firstname;lastname

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String firstname;

    @Column
    private String lastname;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookAuthors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Book> books;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookAuthors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Magazine> magazines;

    public Author() {

    }

    public Author(String email, String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.email = email;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    // title;isbn;bookAuthors;description
    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String isbn;

    @Column(length = 5000)
    private String description;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name="bookAuthors")
    List<String> bookAuthors;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_authors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    List<Author> authors;

    public Book() {

    }

    public Book(String title, String isbn, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.description = description;
    }
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "Magazine")
public class Magazine implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    // title;isbn;bookAuthors;publishedAt
    @Column
    private String title;

    @Column
    private String isbn;

    @ElementCollection
    @Column(name = "bookAuthors")
    List<String> bookAuthors;

    @Column
    private String publishedAt;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "magazine_authors",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "magazine_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    List<Author> authors;

    public Magazine() {

    }

    public Magazine(String title, String isbn, String publishedAt) {

        this.title = title;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.publishedAt = publishedAt;
    }
}
```

The examples of the repository and service files are provided,

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {


    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE book.isbn=:isbn",nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Book> findBookByIsbn(String isbn);
}
```

The service file,

```
@Service
public class BookService {


    private BookRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public void setBookRepository(BookRepository BookRepository) {
        this.repository = BookRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Optional<Book> findById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return (List<Book>) repository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Book save(Book Product) {
        return repository.save(Product);
    }

    @Transactional
    public <S extends Book> List<Book> saveAll(List<Book> students) {

        List<Book> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (students == null) {
            return result;
        }

        for (Book student : students) {
            result.add(repository.save(student));
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void deleteAll() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public Optional<Book> findBookByIsbn(String isbn){
        return repository.findBookByIsbn(isbn);
    }
}
```

When I tried to save the books data, I write the code,

```
String bookFilePath = "/Users/Chaklader/IdeaProjects/Publications/src/main/resources/data/books.csv";
        List<Book> books = new BookCsvFileReader(authorService).readBooksCsvData(bookFilePath);
        bookService.saveAll(books);
```

I get the error,

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "'null-walter@echocat.org' (AUTHOR: ID BIGINT NOT NULL)"; SQL statement:
insert into book_book_authors (books_id, book_authors) values (?, ?) [22018-196]
```

How do I correct it?

**Update**

```
BookCsvFileRead.java

public class BookCsvFileReader extends CsvFileReader {

    private AuthorService authorService;

    public BookCsvFileReader(AuthorService service) {
        this.authorService = service;
    }

    public List<Book> readBooksCsvData(String fileName) throws IOException {

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            List<List<String>> lines = CsvFileReader.readCsvFile(fileName);

            lines.remove(0);

            for (List<String> line : lines) {

                String title = line.get(0);
                String isbn = line.get(1);

                String[] emails = line.get(2).split(",");

                List<String> bookAuthors = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String email : emails) {
                    bookAuthors.add(email);
                }

                String description = line.get(3);

                Book book = new Book(title, isbn, description, bookAuthors);
                book.setBookAuthors(bookAuthors);

                books.add(book);
            }
        }

        //
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return books;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you get to that situation, but the answer is probably hidden in a piece of code you did not add to your question. Could you also add the `readBooksCsvData` method of your `BookCsvFileReader` to your question?

I believe the underlying problem is that your CSV files use email address strings as author IDs, but you modeled your `Author` entity class to use a numeric serial ID instead. Something in that CSV reader probably tries to map that email address to the author table's numeric ID column.

Comment: readBooksCsvData method but I also corrected the code based on your assumption which is VERY correct. I will write an answer with the corrected code later.

Comment: If I understand the model correctly, you need to modify the following 2 lines in the Author class (change the mappedBy):

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Book> books;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Magazine> magazines;

to point to the entities rather than the element collections

Comment: @osamayaccoub  why so? Please explain

Comment: if you want a bidirectional many to many realtion between the author and the book and the author and the magazine, the `mappedBy` should refer back the the element annotated by `@ManyToMany` rather than the element annotated by the `@ElementCollection`

Comment: I think you are right and I deleted the `@ElementCollection` tag from the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem was that the CSV files use email address strings as author IDs, but the Author entity class is modeled to use a numeric serial ID instead. I modified the code as below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    // email;firstname;lastname

    @Column
    private String firstname;

    @Column
    private String lastname;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookAuthors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Book> books;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookAuthors", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Magazine> magazines;

    public Author() {

    }

    public Author(String email, String firstname, String lastname) {
        this.email = email;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }}
```

So, the code can read and save data from the CSV file properly now.